# yii2 only show items where relation count is greater than 0

Tags: sql, yii2

So i have the following relationship within my Brands model, now what I am wanting to do within my BrandsSearch model is to count the number of records within the join table (BrandsReviews) and then if it's <= 0 or null then filter it out/not return in within the data set.

```
public function getBrandsReviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BrandsReviews::className(), ['brands_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Something like (however it says Invalid use of group function):

```
->andFilterWhere(['>', 'count(brands.brandsReviews)', 0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are filtering  for aggregated  function as count() or sum() 
you could use andFilterHaving()

```
  ->andFilterHaving(['>', 'count(brands.brandsReviews)', 0]);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#andFilterHaving()-detail